# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install PyQt5" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Tags: python, docker, apple-m1, arm64, docker-build

I'm facing issues while trying to install PyQt5 in a Docker container running on my M1 Mac. I'm getting an "exit code 1" error, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here are the details of the error:

```
     => ERROR [ 4/10] RUN pip install PyQt5                                                  15.1s
------
 > [ 4/10] RUN pip install PyQt5:
1.905 Collecting PyQt5
2.101   Downloading PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
2.923      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
3.495   Installing build dependencies: started
14.73   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
14.73   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
14.84   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
14.84   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
14.95   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
14.95   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
14.95   
14.95   × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
14.95   │ exit code: 1
14.95   ╰─> [22 lines of output]
14.95       Traceback (most recent call last):
14.95         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
14.95           main()
14.95         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
14.95           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
14.95         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
14.95           whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
14.95         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jdwoawmc/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
14.95           project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
14.95         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jdwoawmc/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
14.95           project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
14.95         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jdwoawmc/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
14.95           self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
14.95         File "/tmp/pip-install-mzeftfht/pyqt5_bf3035fa4f10443a8e3fc8e9719e36c0/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
14.95           super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
14.95         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jdwoawmc/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
14.95           super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
14.95         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jdwoawmc/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
14.95           self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
14.95         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jdwoawmc/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
14.95           raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
14.95       sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
14.95       [end of output]
14.95   
14.95   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
14.96 error: metadata-generation-failed
14.96 
14.96 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
14.96 ╰─> See above for output.
14.96 
14.96 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
14.96 hint: See above for details.
14.96 
14.96 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.2.1
14.96 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
Dockerfile:25
--------------------
  23 |     WORKDIR /app
  24 |     
  25 | >>> RUN pip install PyQt5
  26 |     
  27 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install PyQt5" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

#### Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Python 3.10 image for arm64 architecture (M1 Mac)
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Install PyQt5 and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    libxcb-xinerama0 \
    libxcb-icccm4 \
    libxcb-image0 \
    libxcb-keysyms1 \
    libxcb-render-util0 \
    libxcb-xkb1 \
    libxcb-render0 \
    libxcb-shm0 \
    libxcb-shape0 \
    libxcb-randr0 \
    libxcb-screensaver0 \
    libxcb-xfixes0 \
    libxcb-sync1 \
    build-essential

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install PyQt5


COPY . .

# Copy your application code into the container
COPY . /app

# Set any other environment variables or commands as needed

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup.py install
RUN python setup.py build
RUN pip install map

# Run your Python script
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

I've tried a few solutions mentioned in other Stack Overflow threads, such as updating pip and installing build essentials, but the issue persists. I suspect there might be something specific to the M1 Mac architecture that's causing the problem.

Additionally, I attempted to use a different Docker image ([jozo/pyqt5](https://hub.docker.com/r/jozo/pyqt5)) with QEMU emulation, but I encountered the same error during the installation of PyQt5.

Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this PyQt5 installation issue on an M1 Mac in a Docker container would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Running a GUI application in a container at all is hard and non-portable (you will need a MacOS-based X Window System server on your host, for example).  Can you use PyQt5 directly on your MacOS host, maybe installing Qt using a package manager like Homebrew, without involving Docker?  If this _must_ run in a container, the "exit code: 1" message pretty much just means "it didn't work"; can you [edit] the question to include more of the error?

Comment: I can install PyQt5 via Rosetta without a problem and everything works without docker. The purpose of me putting it into docker is to be able to setup the software on ARM A57 64-bit (Jetson Nano) because it is a challenge to install all of the packages there